# Parsing XML Data or convert to NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, xcode, parsing, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have xml data that is retrieved from a server and I need to remove some parts of it in order to set up my tableview.  I am converting this data to an NSDictionary, but I think it might be easier to parse (is that the right word?) the xml data rather than messing with it once it's already converted. Here's a sample of the xml data.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <response status="ok">
 <rosters records_per_page="50" page_count="1" page="1" total_record_count="11">
 <roster class_id="685343" role="T" user_id="968428" roster_id="16257539">
 <class name="Haiku API Keys" shortname="haiku_api" end_date="2011-12-20" code=""      
 import_id="" id="685343" description="" teacher_id="971456" year="2012" 
 organization_id="134146" active="false"/>
 </roster>
 <roster class_id="512296" role="S" user_id="968428" roster_id="10456326">
 <class name="Physics AP" shortname="physics-ap_0406-01" end_date="2012-05-02" 
 code="PHYSICSA_0406-01" import_id="0406-01-2012" id="512296" description="DESCRIPTION" 
 teacher_id="968968" year="2012" organization_id="134148" active="true"/>
 </roster>
```

What I want to do is remove the data that has the object "false" for the key "active."  This would leave me the data with the class name of Physics AP.  Is this possible to do with xml data or should I try to remove this data once it is an NSDictionary?  This is what the converted NSDictionary looks like.

```
 (
 {
response =     {
    "@status" = ok;
    rosters =         {
        "@page" = 1;
        "@page_count" = 1;
        "@records_per_page" = 50;
        "@total_record_count" = 11;
        roster =             (
                            {
                "@class_id" = 685343;
                "@role" = T;
                "@roster_id" = 16257539;
                "@user_id" = 968428;
                class =                     {
                    "@active" = false;
                    "@code" = "";
                    "@description" = "";
                    "@end_date" = "2011-12-20";
                    "@id" = 685343;
                    "@import_id" = "";
                    "@name" = "Haiku API Keys";
                    "@organization_id" = 134146;
                    "@shortname" = "haiku_api";
                    "@teacher_id" = 971456;
                    "@year" = 2012;
                };
            },
                            {
                "@class_id" = 512296;
                "@role" = S;
                "@roster_id" = 10456326;
                "@user_id" = 968428;
                class =                     {
                    "@active" = true;
                    "@code" = "PHYSICSA_0406-01";
                    "@description" = "DESCRIPTION";
                    "@end_date" = "2012-05-02";
                    "@id" = 512296;
                    "@import_id" = "0406-01-2012";
                    "@name" = "Physics AP";
                    "@organization_id" = 134148;
                    "@shortname" = "physics-ap_0406-01";
                    "@teacher_id" = 968968;
                    "@year" = 2012;
                };
            },
            }
```

Just the way the xml data is formatted makes me think it would be easier to accomplish by parsing it, but I don't know if it is possible, or what method to use.  If you have a way to accomplish this by using the xml data or the NSDictionary I would love to hear it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same XMLReader you've used, and I like it.

If I were to solve the problem, here's my solution, after you've got the dictionary you just need to create a new array of dictionary, to be specific a new array of roster, like this:

```
NSArray *roster = [[[theDictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"rosters"] objectForKey:@"roster"];

NSMutableArray *newRoster = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<[roster count];i++){
    NSDictionary *aRoster = [roster objectAtIndex:i];
    //filter the array and add it to the mutable array
    if([[[aRoster objectForKey:@"class"] objectForKey:@"@@active"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
        //this way we only add those data whose active is "true"
        [newRoster addObject:aRoster];
    }
}

//do what you want with the new roster
NSLog(@"newRoster = %@",newRoster);
```

In this case im just assuming you only going to use the the array of "roster" tags and you want to remove those tags whose "active" attributes is equal to string "false".

Don't forget to release the newRoster when you are done with it.

The XMLReader is quite tedious to work with when it comes to attributes, correct me if I have some errors since i dont have a mac to use today

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Next time, before you post, please check out the FAQ on grammar and code formatting guidelines, as they are appreciated and expected here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to xml parsing in objective c I would suggest you to use TBXML (http://tbxml.co.uk/) library.. parse your xml using this library and store what content you want in Array or dictionary (leave what you don't want).. and use the array or dictionary to create your table..

Comment: I'm already using XMLReader at https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary.  Will TBXML accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I just don't know how to only add the title objects under the condition of the active object being "true". The two keys are in the same dictionary, but I dont know of a method that lets me look at the "active" object and eliminate the "title" object if the active object is "false". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes with tbxml you can check the condition you are looking and can only parse or store content you need